# How do I see which documents are open?

Tags: c#, javascript, mysql, asp.net, visual-web-developer

This may seem like a stupid question but bear with me.

So I am using **Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express** (because it's free and was recommended to me), and I am using the 'Find and replace' tool a lot to change variable names and so on. On the top I can have 2 documents open **"Test.aspx"** and **"Test.aspx.cs"** and I want to change the varible name "Auction" to "AuctionID" for example. I put in replace all in the currently open documents. This, for some reason, changes the names in another file - let's call it **"Test2.aspx**" for some reason even though I can not see that I have it up. And I click it down and try again - same thing.

Is there any way to close all of them and only open the ones I want again? Or is this just some weird bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Find and Replace window, Check the option on "Look In", drop down it should be in current document, or current open files.

Comment: Unrelated to the answer, I recommend you look into using the [Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40747). It has a number of enhancements and is also free.

Comment: I used that before but it was only free for 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Find & Replace window has several options for the scope of your replacement.

- **Current Document** (only if you have a document open)
- **All Open Documents** (only if you have more than one document open)
- **Current Project** (only if you have a current project open)
- **Current Solution**
- **Selection** (only if you have a block of text currently highlighted in the editor)

You'll see this as a dropdown menu under the option for "Look In" when viewing the Find/Replace window (<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>).

[image: Find/Replace Window]

By the way, are you actually trying to rename a variable or type name (as opposed to random text)? The best way to do that is to right click the variable or type name, then go into Refactor, then Rename. It will "know" where the variable/type is being referenced and replace all references to it.

Comment: The Refactor part helped :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be tabs within your visual studio. Every time you have one open, it should show it as another tab you can switch through, but I know I have made mistakes using the find and replace with 'All Opened Document's' selected, so I would recommend just using "Current Document" instead, which will just search the current document you are working in.

Answer (score 0):

Below the replace textbox, there is a combobox with these options:

```
Current Document
All Open Documents
Current Project
Entire Solution 
Selection //this is added when there is a selection
```

Before hitting Replace All button choose the option that fits you.

Comment: All Open Documents gave me more documents than I could see being open on the top tab.